# Why double-headed arrows when the direction of node is specified?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am quite puzzled when drawing the connection of nodes.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{1F4E79}
\definecolor{salmon}{HTML}{FF9C6B}
\tikzstyle{cell} = [rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=salmon]
\tikzstyle{state} = [rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=darkblue]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8},node distance=1.5cm]
    \node (0) [state] {\textcolor{white}{feature extraction}};
    \node (1) [cell, below of=0] {invertBotConE2\_f48\_k1\_b4\_noskip};
    \node (2) [cell, below of=1] {invertBotConE2\_f16\_k3\_b4\_noskip};
    \draw [arrow] (0) -- (1);
    \draw [arrow] (1) -- (2);
    \draw  (0.east)  [arrow]  edge [out=0, in=0, out looseness=4, in looseness=4]  (2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

0,2 are my nodes. When `east` is specified, it creates an arrow on node 0. If removed, it disappears. What if I would like to put `0.south` as the start of the edge?

[image: double-headed connection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to` instead of `edge`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{1F4E79}
\definecolor{salmon}{HTML}{FF9C6B}
\tikzset{cell/.style={rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text
centered, draw=black, fill=salmon},
state/.style={rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text
centered, draw=black, fill=darkblue},
arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8},node distance=1.5cm]
    \node (0) [state] {\textcolor{white}{feature extraction}};
    \node (1) [cell, below of=0] {invertBotConE2\_f48\_k1\_b4\_noskip};
    \node (2) [cell, below of=1] {invertBotConE2\_f16\_k3\_b4\_noskip};
    \draw [arrow] (0) -- (1);
    \draw [arrow] (1) -- (2);
    \draw  (0.east)  [arrow]  to[out=0, in=0, out looseness=4, in looseness=4]  (2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or use the appropriate syntax with `edge`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{1F4E79}
\definecolor{salmon}{HTML}{FF9C6B}
\tikzset{cell/.style={rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text
centered, draw=black, fill=salmon},
state/.style={rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text
centered, draw=black, fill=darkblue},
arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8},node distance=1.5cm]
    \node (0) [state] {\textcolor{white}{feature extraction}};
    \node (1) [cell, below of=0] {invertBotConE2\_f48\_k1\_b4\_noskip};
    \node (2) [cell, below of=1] {invertBotConE2\_f16\_k3\_b4\_noskip};
    \draw [arrow] (0) -- (1);
    \draw [arrow] (1) -- (2);
    \draw  (0.east)    edge[arrow,out=0, in=0, out looseness=4, in looseness=4]  (2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Attempt of an)**explanation**: `edge` inserts a new path. So you had two paths, and two arrows.

Comment: `to` works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MeadowMuffins `edge` also works *if* you put `arrow` inside its arguments. (BTW, please consider using `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`.)