# tikz arrow heads in both ends

Tags: tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [-] (0, 0) edge node[above] {$\epsilon_f$} (5, 0);
  \draw [<->] (1, -1) edge node[below] {$\epsilon_f$} (4, -1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is :

[image: result]

Why does the left-end has strange arrowhead? How can I make it a normal <- arrowhead?

Comment: Those are actually two arrowheads pointing to the same spot, though I wouldn't know why the other one is drawn. Note that this also won't happen if you use `to` or `--` instead of `edge`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470975/121799

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [-] (0, 0) edge node[above] {$\epsilon_f$} (5, 0);
  \draw  (1, -1) edge[<->] node[below] {$\epsilon_f$} (4, -1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]