# Getting double arrows in TiKZ even though a simple directed edge is required

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Does someone know why I am getting a double arrow instead of a simple directed edge with the following use case scenario? How can I get a single arrowed edge instead?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,shapes}

\newcommand\kk[1]{\textcolor{RoyalBlue}{\text{\textup{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}}}}
\newcommand\cc[1]{\textcolor{Sepia}{\text{\textup{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{scope}[node distance=0pt]
\def\width{9ex}

\tikzstyle{frame}=[
    font=\scriptsize,
    %text width=7ex,
    draw,
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=20,
    rectangle split part align={center, left},
    rectangle split empty part height=0ex,
    rectangle split empty part depth=0ex,
    rectangle split empty part width=0ex,
    start chain=going right,
    rectangle split horizontal
]

%%MAIN
\node (main) [frame,
    rectangle split parts=4,
    rectangle split part fill={Fuchsia!30,
                               teal!30,
                               teal!30,
                               teal!30] at (0,.7) {%
\nodepart{one} 
    \centering \kk{node size}
\nodepart{two} \centering \cc{outgoing offset}
\nodepart{three} \centering \cc{$id$}
    \nodepart{four} \cc{M}
};



\draw[->] (main.one north) edge [bend left=10] (main.three north);
\draw[->] (main.two south) edge [bend right=10] (main.four south);  


\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tikz Image with non-intended double arrow]

Comment: `\draw (main.one north) edge [->,bend left=10] (main.three north);
\draw (main.two south) edge [->,bend right=10] (main.four south);  ` See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470975/121799

Comment: I've just did it after I saw the updated comment with the link.