# Eliminate tail of curved arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I tried to draw a curved arrow like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->,thick] (2,1) edge[bend left=50] (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, there is an undesired "tail" of the arrow. How can I eliminate it?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why double-headed arrows when the direction of node is specified?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470973/why-double-headed-arrows-when-the-direction-of-node-is-specified) Solution from the duplicate: use `to`, i.e., `\draw[->,thick] (2,1) to[bend left=50] (3,2);`. But still good MWE and clear question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define as `node` the starting and the ending points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (2,1) {};
\node (B) at (3,2) {};
\draw[-latex,thick] (A) edge[bend left=50] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]